# Why are static methods not available in Singleton Instance?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton

I create generic type class of name `SingletonGenerator<>`. For implement Singelton Design Pattern. So, below code is it the class:

**SingletonGenerator.cs**

```
public class SingletonGenerator<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static readonly Lazy<T> _instance =
      new Lazy<T>(() => new T(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    private SingletonGenerator()
    {
    }

    public static T Instance => _instance.Value;
}
```

And, create other class for get instance:

**AppDb.cs**

```
public class AppDbContext
{
    public string Database { get; set; }
    private static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public static void Send()
    {
    }

    public void Go()
    {
    }
}
```

In **Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = SingletonGenerator<AppDbContext>.Instance;

        var database = context.Database; // is available 
        var connection = context.ConnectionString; //is not available

        context.Go(); // is available 
        context.Send(); // is not available
    }
}
```

My Question is **Why are static methods not available in Singleton Instance?**

And My code is correct?

Comment: well... these are `static` not `instance` members, so you access them from the type not the instance: `AppDbContext.ConnectionString`

Comment: Can you not read compile errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A static member cannot be referenced through an instance. Instead, it
>   is referenced through the type name.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).

The problem has nothing to do with the fact your instance is a singleton, to reference a static member use the type name:

```
AppDbContext.Send();
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters `ConnectionString` is `private`. You can't access it from another class.

You also can't accesses `static` method from an instance. You need to use the class

```
AppDbContext.ConnectionString;

AppDbContext.Send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well because they are static and belong to type (in your case AppDbContext) and not object instance, with singleton pattern you still create one instance even though the property for accessing it is static. So you can call them with type name

```
var connection = AppDbContext.ConnectionString;
AppDbContext.Send();
```